# C# T4 Template "Error" During Transformation

Tags: c#, t4

I have a C# project which has 8 T4 templates in it which transform my models/services/repo etc automatically based on my DBML.

Everything is transforming fine and receiving no errors when actually compiling the project, however I do receive the following when actually running the `Transform All Templates` command. Even though it doesn't appear to be actually affecting anything, I'm just trying to get the bottom of this error. Any thoughts?

```
Error   44  Running transformation: System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array. at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplatingA0408758CBA091AEC8619A75CCA2AD32.GeneratedTextTransformation.TransformText() at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplating.TransformationRunner.RunTransformation(TemplateProcessingSession session, String source, ITextTemplatingEngineHost host, String& result)      1   1
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/IXkPT.png

[image]

Comment: Does it go anywhere when you double click on it?

Comment: Bobson - No it just sits there. Here is a picture of the error.

Comment: Bizarre.  If you're using Visual Studio 2012, try [debugging](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/TinyHappyFeatures1T4TemplateDebuggingInVisualStudio2012.aspx) the template.  If you're on 2010, try [this](http://adventuresindotnet.blogspot.com/2011/11/debugging-t4-templates.html) instead.  *Caveat: I never got debugging T4 to work.*

Answer (score 0):

Is there a T4 file in the solution or any of the projects that doesn't actually exist locally? perhaps it wasn't in the source that was downloaded. This could show up as a Yellow exclamation point instead of an error in the solution explorer.

Also you didn't mention if you manually ran each template to make sure they all run just fine.